# Cannot find module 'live-server' (locally installed)

Tags: npm

I have been trying to run babel and live-server locally , however when calling for 'npm run build' or 'npm run serve' I get the following error:

```
> boilerplate@1.0.0 serve C:\Users\sasaa\OneDrive\Documents\HTMl&CSS\j-14-05-globals\boilerplate
> live-server public

'CSS\j-14-05-globals\boilerplate\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sasaa\OneDrive\Documents\live-server\live-server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! boilerplate@1.0.0 serve: `live-server public`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the boilerplate@1.0.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sasaa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-05T00_21_18_216Z-debug.log
```

This is the package-json:

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "input.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public",
    "build": "babel src/index.js --out-file public/scripts/bundle.js --presets env --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

I am using Windows 10 with Git Bash
npm version 6.13.4
node v13.5.0

Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` again?

Comment: Yes, I still get the same error. Also tried reinstalling node and npm, I still get the same error. I was thinking it could be related to path variable but haven't managed to make it work. Any other suggestions? @NaorLevi